# Meeting every logical condition in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with 6,000 obs

```
SubjectID  : int   1,2,3,4...
Arthritis  : logi  FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE
Stroke     : logi  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Diabetes   : logi  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Cancer     : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

I am trying to find rows where every disease is absent.  I can do it for a single disease with this:

```
subset(RHV.FINAL, Arthritis=="FALSE")
```

I have tried this for all diseases, which works, but is cumbersome:

```
subset(RHV.FINAL, Arthritis=="FALSE" & Stroke=="FALSE" & Diabetes=="FALSE" & Cancer=="FALSE")
```

Is there a more eloquent solution?

Comment: testing for `FALSE` isn't the same as testing for equality with the string `"FALSE"`, be careful with that! Your example would become `subset(RHV.FINAL, !(Arthritis | Stroke | Diabetes | Cancer))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you not use `rowSums`? It's  abit hard to tell with the `str` of your data as you have posted it. A small example to recreate in an R session would be good (`dput`).

```
df [rowSums( df ) == 0 , ]
```

For example...

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame( id = 1:5,
            A = sample( c(T,F) , 5 , repl = T ),
            B = sample( c(T,F) , 5 , repl = T ),
            C = sample( c(T,F) , 5 , repl = T ))

  id     A     B     C
1  1  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
2  2 FALSE FALSE  TRUE
3  3  TRUE FALSE FALSE
4  4 FALSE FALSE FALSE
5  5 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE


# df[,-1] to exclude id variable in first column (thanks @DidzisElferts)
df[ rowSums(df[,-1]) == 0 , ] 
  id     A     B     C
4  4 FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: You should select only part of columns in rowSums(df) as first column is integer (ID) so sum never will be 0, something like df[rowSums(df[,2:5])==0,]

Comment: @DidzisElferts thaks, or I guess `rowSums( df[,-1] )`

Comment: Great, I have learnt a new command. And thanks as well @DidzisElferts

Comment: cheeky alternative is `df[ !as.logical(rowSums(df[,-1])), ]`